# Apache redirection with port

Tags: apache, redirect, port

I have just reinstalled my apache server on debian 8
But I can not go from "http://IP: 8080" to "https://IP:8080"
Here is my redirection

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I cannot see any mentioning of a port number in those rules, so the default port 80 applies.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that it is impossible to operate both, http and https on a single port.

Comment: Last but not least: keep in mind that you cannot operate an https server with a valid certificate on an IP address base. You need a domain name (actually a host name) for that which the certificate is issued for. Sure, you can use https with a self signed certificate, but is that really what you want?

Comment: I would like my final URL to be https://www.worldcube.fr:8080

Comment: Sure, no one objects. You have to configure it. But still all what I said above is true and my first two commands should be considered by you. So: _have_ you configured your http server to serve https on that port? We cannot do that for you, you have to. For the rewriting from http to https: what server should listen to the http request and redirect the client? As said: it has to be a different one than the https server. And one last thing: why would one want to operate a https server on such a non standard port? That only annoys, since you have to specify the port number in each and every URL

Comment: I currently configure apache to redirect all requests from http to https, I'm currently listening to default ports 80 & 443
I would just like my: 8087 which is a bot disc either in https: 3

Sorry for my bad english: /

Comment: And you don't think all that is important information that should be present in the question itself? Apart from that: as said in my first comment: your rewrite rule targets do not show any port number. You cannot redirect to a non standard port without that. How should the client _guess_ the port number? So add the port number to the target URLs!

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry again ...
No rewrite rules apply to worldcube.fr:8087 :/

Comment: Don't be sorry, what for? Most of us are non native English speakers :-) But I am afraid that I do not understand what you try to express with your last comment. I was referring to the rewrite rules you specified: `RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` which has to be change to something like `RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%:8087{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`.

Comment: https://www.worldcube.fr:8087/ return https://www.worldcube.fr:8087/ :/

Comment: There is no sense in this. I try to explain, point out and elaborate and all that comes back from you is half sentences where you apparently expect me to guess what you might mean. Sorry, but it is in _your_ interest to explain what you want in such way that others can understand you and are motivated to help.

Comment: Okay I'll try to be clearer ^^
My apache server listens to the 80 & 443 classic ports, I redirect my http requests to https, except for the ip of my server that needs a small bypass
I then sinusbot which is a bot for discord that gives me an interface on port 8087, so accessible by http://worldcube.fr:8087 but not by https://worldcube.fr:8087 it gives me an error SSL

Comment: Sorry, but still everything but clear: this comment contradicts what you wrote before and in the question. And where does that "ip" come in, is it a client or a server ip address? Even more unclear now. If it is a client ip address then certainly you cannot redirect from https to http, that will be refused by browsers for good reason. You could implement an internal proxy solution which allows the client to use https to the "front end server" (apache) whilst that internal server on port 8087 still uses http.

Comment: And a general remark: please stop posting all such details and information in comments.There is an `edit` link below your question, _use it_.